# Adding binary files to git repo, convention

Tags: git, github

I'm doing school project (couple of java programs), and I'm using git for version control.
As I plan on saving the repo for newer students attending the same course, I also want to add PDF and MP4 files that are basis for homework.

I understand that I shouldn't add binary files (that aren't going to be changed ever) to git repo, so what is the exact convention for doing this sort of thing? Binary files are in collective about 5mb or so.

Ultimatelly I'm asking if there is a specific documentation system linked to repo or something on git(hub) that allows me to upload files that aren't going to be changed.

Comment: Binary files are fine to be included. Git is not _the best tool for them_, but it's ok to have them. What you should not include is binaries **that come out of the build process**.... say, a java project? Then ignore the .class files that come from the sources of the project as they should be built from _the sources_ that you are tracking.

Comment: thanks, I'm aware of that... I just thought that "dragging" immutable files through the VC history isn't recommended at all.

Comment: Why is that? If the files are part of the project, they should be in... if you ask me.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding binary files at GitHub, I believe you have to pay attention to 2 aspects:

1. If it's legal to store them there (copyright, DMCA) - check this https://docs.github.com/en/github/site-policy/github-terms-of-service#f-copyright-infringement-and-dmca-policy
2. If their size is allowed - https://docs.github.com/en/github/managing-large-files/working-with-large-files/conditions-for-large-files

Up to 50 MB, it's fine. If they are really big (GB), you may need to store them in a separate repository - https://docs.github.com/en/github/administering-a-repository/managing-repository-settings/managing-git-lfs-objects-in-archives-of-your-repository

From the GIT perspective, if your file is not altered, GIT will calculate the file hash and, if there's no change, the repository won't be affected, which means that your GIT client won't try to upload/download a file that hasn't been changed.

Comment: yeah that's fine i'm just asking in which way is this usually done

Comment: @FedjaMladenovic. add, commit, push usually

Comment: @FedjaMladenovic the way it's done is - if it's less then 50 MB, github does not care. If it's more than 100 MB, github will ask you to use GIT LFS (3rd link from my answer)

Comment: As a side comment, I don't know where MD5 comes into the picture. You meant sha1/sha256?

Comment: sorry @eftshift0 you're right, GIT uses SHA, not MD5. I've edited the answer. Thanks for the heads up